# EC+EC2 auto scale instance on deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, continuous-deployment, autoscaling

I have an ECS cluster running service and task that sits on an EC2 machine.  The task is big and takes up the whole machine its running on.  Is there any way to set up ECS & EC2 to scale temporally on deployments to create a new instance, run the new task then stop the old pre-deployment task?

So far tried to play with the auto-scaling on both EC2 & ECS separately but it seems to me that the conditions for scaling are down to CPU or memory utilization, however as my task takes up the whole instance there are no alarms that could be triggered on deployment as there's just no suitable instance to start the task on.

Right now I have the services running as DAEMON, so it's one per instance, and autoscaling seems to be disabled for it.  During deployments, it drains the old task before starting the new one creating downtime.   To set the service type to REPLICA, scaling can be enabled, however, it's based on instance resource utilization and I can't seem to figure out how I would create a new instance on deployments.

I am missing something or interpreting how these auto-scalers work wrong, as I can't seem to see a nice way to deploy without affecting the current task sort of having just an unused instance sitting there running in the background all the time(wasting money).

Comment: When you say "takes up the whole machine" does it max out the CPU/RAM ? If so autoscaling based on resources should do the trick. If not, then your code might be poorly designed

Comment: Yeah, it's some containers with some pretty heavy NLP workloads, so it does take up the whole(or most of the memory) instance that I'm using. In theory, I could use a larger instance size, but as I'm already using a t3.large I kinda want to keep costs down.  

I don't really think scaling based on resources works here either though, as that is based on active resources, whereas for deployment the resource hasn't been provisioned yet, if that makes sense

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I have exactly the same issue.